# Firefox syntax issue when placing an <li> inside of an <a> - not linkable?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a css sprite navigation bar where the li's are wrapped in a href tags for linking...

```
<div id="header">
    <ul>
        <a href="/"><li id="supplements-link"></li></a>
        <a href="/tutorials/"><li id="tutorials-link"></li></a>
        <a href="/blog/"><li id="blog-link"></li></a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

It works fine for me in Safari, Chrome, Opera & IE - but the links aren't active in Firefox, and when I look at the code in Firebug, Firefox renders the a href and li tags as separate lines:

```
<div id="header">
    <ul>
        <li id="supplements-link"></li>
        <a href="/"></a>
        <li id="tutorials-link"></li>
        <a href="/tutorials/"></a>
        <li id="blog-link"></li>
        <a href="/blog/"></a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: Awesome - thanks so much for all the answers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`li` elements are the only elements that can be children of `ol` or `ul`. Your HTML is [invalid](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://work.arounds.org/sandbox/65/run&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) at the moment.

Please wrap the lis around the `a`s.

Comment: Yep - the LIs are the containers, the As are the content.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to style up the `a` inside the li making it's width and height 100%, here's some other suggestions:

http://doctype.com/make-li-clickable-target-url

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put the anchor tags inside the LI elements? That's how it's usually done.

Answer (score 0):

`<ul>` doesn't support `<a>` as a child, your html is not properly formatted, try this instead:

```
<div id="header">
    <ul>
        <li id="supplements-link"><a href="/"></a></li>
        <li id="tutorials-link"><a href="/tutorials/"></a></li>
        <li id="blog-link"><a href="/blog/"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a's inside li's, and then `display: block;` in your CSS, this will make the whole `li` a link instead of just the text, which I think is what you're probably trying to achieve?

That way you then add padding etc to your `<a>` tag to make the link blocks bigger. This will solve the FF issue:

CSS:

```
#header ul li a {
display: block;
padding: 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    <ul>
        <li id="supplements-link"><a href="/">Supps link</a></li>
        <li id="tutorials-link"><a href="/tutorials/">Tuts link</a></li>
        <li id="blog-link"><a href="/blog/">Blog link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```